# Transforming pandas dataframe to specific timeseries structure

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a pandas dataframe with baseball data, like this:

```
 data = [['1','2006', 10], ['1','2007', 8], ['1','2008', 14],['2','2010', 54], ['2','2011', 50], ['2','2012', 14]] 
 df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['player_id', 'year','homeruns'])
```

My objective is to transform this dataframe so that each line has the player_id, the year t, homeruns at year t, homeruns at t-1, and homeruns at t+1, and to have all possible lines with year t for which there exists t-1, t and t+1 in the df.

In my example, my output would be:

```
data_output = [['1','2007', 8,10,14], ['2','2011', 50,54,14]]
df_output = pd.DataFrame(dataoutput, columns = ['player_id','year_t','homeruns_t','homeruns_t_minus_1', 'homeruns_t_plus_1'])
```

Is there any good way to do that? Is this part of any python time series package?

Comment: Can there be more than 3 lines for each ID?

Comment: Yes, each line is a year of statistics for a player. Some players played in more seasons than others.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisMercier what sets the year, is it always the second year ?

Comment: Any year in the output data has to contain date of the previous and next year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want homeruns for year, year minus one, year plus one for each `player_id` (assuming the data is sorted by year):

```
data = [['1','2006', 10], ['1','2007', 8], ['1','2008', 14],['2','2010', 54], ['2','2011', 50], ['2','2012', 14]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['player_id', 'year','homeruns'])

df['homeruns_t_minus_1'] = df.groupby(['player_id'])['homeruns'].shift()
df['homeruns_t_plus_1'] = df.groupby(['player_id'])['homeruns'].shift(-1)
print( df[~(df['homeruns_t_minus_1'].isna() | df['homeruns_t_plus_1'].isna())].astype(int) )
```

Prints:

```
   player_id  year  homeruns  homeruns_t_minus_1  homeruns_t_plus_1
1          1  2007         8                  10                 14
4          2  2011        50                  54                 14
```